# I'm trying to hide a <div> via javascript hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

```
        $("#" + id).hide(2000);
```

I have a div I'm trying to hide thusly, but doesn't seem to be doing the animation properly.

Just disappears.

Comment: You'll have to give us more info.  How about a working/non-working example?

Comment: It's a div section i'm making with ajax, and in the div id is processed by js script which deletes it from the php after this command, but I want it to slide away before that.

Comment: You need to program what animation you want. E.g. slideToggle(2000) or fadeOut(2000)

Comment: It works here in this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XDQwU/.

Comment: Make sure you don't add the same id multiple times

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, my guess is that your code is deleting it right after the animation STARTED.  The animation is an asychronous process.  Your code will continue to run right after the animation is started.  If you are then removing the object after the call to `hide()`, then you will be removing it before the animation has completed and it will "just disappear" rather than fade out slowly.

To fix that, you will need a completion event on the animation and you will need to remove it upon completion.

You will need something like this:

```
$("#" + id).hide(2000, function() {
    // remove it from the page here upon completion of the animation
});
```

Just to show people that the .hide(2000) function works just fine, here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XDQwU/.

Comment: +1 good call, that's definitely what's happening. @nick move the code that removes the element into a success function for .hide() and you should be good to go.

Comment: Do I need to be adding the element to the css??
the class is made dynamically with <div id="102"> (for example)
then theres a <a class="delete" onClick="del(102)">X</a> which triggers the del(id) function where my hide function is